# improving query performance for a table in redshift

Tags: sorting, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

I am new to Redshift and I worked with B-tree and bitmpa indexes in Oracle.

we have many tables in Star schema. Fact table with several fk columns to dimensiin tables.
there us a dimension table amd we often use one column PART_NuMBER in where clause in Oracle.
The is very high cardinality column almost all values are unique. We will do that in Redshift as well. so I suppose this column should be a good sort key. This table will be joined with fact table . So to use the most efficient merge join then the fk of the fact and pk of the dimension should be distkey and sort key.
IfI define the pk as sort key then the column part_number will be not my leading sort key that can be used efficient as predicate in the where clause. In that case the table will be full scanned for one value or am I wrong?

what will be the best practice in such scenariis.
The fact table has many other fk columns to another dimensions so the other could be defined in the compound key but will be used marge join when joining to another dimensions?

I am bit confused.
In Oracle the bitmap could be defined for many columns and it doesn't matter the order of predicates in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a number of things to address in this post but let me cut to the likely answer.

I suspect that you need to define your dim tables as DISTSTYLE ALL and sort by part_number.  There are some limits to doing this based on dim table size that depend on your cluster size / node type.  Unless your dim tables are a significant percentage of you fact table in size you will be best off going this way.

The order of your WHERE predicates doesn’t matter but the order of your compound sort keys on the table does.  I suspect you got these factors mixed.  This is all about getting the most value out of the zone maps of each table.

As to your fact table you will want a set of sort keys that give you good rejection of blocks based on metadata.  This is often not the fks to the dims but can be.  It is common that a date or timestamp will be important as a sort key on your facts but will depend you your query patterns.  Getting this optimized with take a bit of back and forth on your data on queries.

Comment: Weliner. Thanks. This something I don't unferstand. Yiu said order of predicates in where clause doesn't matter. If I have the table sorted on col1 then col2 and I write where col2 then col1 it will be fine? Does the optimizer rewrite it? The problem will be if just col2 is in where clause?. You said sort order in fact table not on fk? why, if it used in joins? predicates will be almost always from Dim tables. Suppose I have Order Name in Dim,do filter to specific one should filter the records in fact table,so Fact fk = Dim pk.

Comment: Redshift looks for every opportunity to use the table metadata to reduce table scanning.  Order of the predicates doesn’t matter but writing your WHERE clause so that clauses can be applied to metadata will matter.  Don’t apply functions to the table columns but what you are comparing them to.  Where clauses are primarily used for table scan reduction so only having one column in the Where clause is fine just reduces the possibility of scan reduction.  PK/FK information is used to optimize JOINs by stopping join actions once one match is found - uniqueness allows for optimization.  cont.

Comment: But be aware that Redshift doesn’t enforce uniqueness of PKs so be sure that you ensure this through some mechanism. Your question on predicates on DIM columns is an important one.  Redshift will infer a predicate on the fact table if there is a simple one for one JOIN requirement (ft.col1 = dt.col1) but this inference can be broken my complexity in your join on clause (ands, ors and such).  However, if the metadata of the fact table doesn’t allow for any meaningful scan reduction then you are scanning the whole fact table (as you fear).  cont.

Comment: If there is one predicate that is used in most queries you will want to have this column in the sort keys of the fact table.  Fact table scan reduction is of major importance as the table gets large.  Setting up the sort keys on the fact table is critical as you only get a few that will be able to significantly impact the table metadata.  I can provide more info on doing this if needed.

Comment: Go ahead,you can provide. Your info is usefull. I will use several columns in my where clause. There will be not one to one relationship with Fact and Dim of course but many to one anf that is true for almost every Fact-Dim combination. For examole the many rows for an order because many supplier for an order or many products in an order etc. 1 order can have 4 products,each product can have several suppliers etc. the predicates could be than order,product,date of creation,supplier etc. cont.

Comment: so If i have predicate product name ord supplier or date or order No. so I have to add it as sort key in my Fact table. So therefor this was the question yo the FK. cause in Fact there is no order No. or product name etc ,just FKs yo the Dims. So to understand it, sort key product name in Dim product and the appropriate FK as sort key in Fact table,right?

Comment: Let me try to lay this out.  Redshift has metadata on each block (1MB of disk storage) of each column of a table.  This metadata hole the minimum and maximum value of the column for this block.  So when you have a WHERE clause, like A = 5, Redshift compares the metadata for column A to see if a block could contain the value 5.  I the block could contain the value 5 then the block is scanned from disk.  If the min value for the block is 8 then it cannot have any value that equals 5 so the block is not read from disk.  This way only a small portion of the table need be read from disk.

Comment: The trick with this system is to select sort keys that allow for  metadata for column A to have narrow ranges of values for each block.  Clearly sorting by A will do this.  But sorting by orthogonal columns will lead to wide ranges of values in A in every block.  Very powerful tool but sometimes hard to set up to get the value you want.  Redshift needs a reference to a column in the table (A) and a value to compare against (5).

Comment: In your case you don’t have WHERE clauses on the fact table directly and it sounds like you don’t have WHERE clauses that can be inferred back to a fact table column.  If your fact table is very large this can be a performance problem.  Correct me if I’m wrong but it sounds like your WHERE clauses are on info that only exists in the dim tables.  This will lead to the fact table being fully scanned with each query (caching will help).  There are a few ways you can attack this but all take some data model work.

Comment: If date ranges are common in queries you can use date info in the fact table to reduce scans.  Dates are common in facts but you case may vary.  You can denormalize data into the fact table from the dims so you have metadata for reducing scanning in the most common cases.  Doing this may mean you need to add additional WHERE clauses or join ons to get the metadata check on the fact table.  In some cases you can make new columns in the fact that allow for classification of records that are important to your biz.  Then use these classifications as WHERE clauses but this depends on your data.

Comment: There’s more detail I can go into or point you to my re:Invent presentation but let’s see if you want to go down any of these paths.  This is why data models for transactional scale up dbs don’t always work on scale out warehouses.  On the JOINing front please look at DISTSTYLE ALL on your dim tables and this will remove a lot of issues.

Comment: Yes as you write. The where clause will address the Dim because order or product are in Dims. In the Fact there almost the FKs yo Dims and the measures. This was one thing that crossed my mind that I can add the product to my Fact but it is not more the classic model of a Fact table. I wonder why when I filter product in the Dim and get several PKs that lead to my Fact FKs the Fact table will not do the same as with product in the Fact and where clause? cont.

Comment: I will then use same predicate for Fact and Dim in my where clause to achieve better scan in both the Fact and Dim? my BI Tool like Tableau will not do that cause you use only one filter for a column to filter,either from Fact or Dim, nobody will use 2 same filters for product

Comment: Two things to note: 1) If there is a join clause like fct.A = dim.A then redshift should apply the condition to both the fact and dim tables.  2) The effectiveness of reducing the amount of table scan based on metadata being up to data (ANALYZE) and how narrow the metadata ranges are for the blocks of the table.  Query reports can show you the "row reduction" of the table scans which gives a good idea on how well reducing scanning is working.  You can also inspect the metadata max and min in the stv_blocklist catalog table.  This can show you how sort keys options might impact scanning.